# some code in<Thinking in java> swich(..) {....} why set default if default mean to do nothing?

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
                switch (Category.categorize(input)) {
            case MONEY:
                amount += input.amount();
                state = ADDING_MONEY;
                break;
            case SHUT_DOWN:
                state = TERMINAL;
                // why ???
            default:
            }
```

these codes come from ,my question is :
why set default,it's nonsense ??  i think it's good to code like this:

```
                    switch (Category.categorize(input)) {
            case MONEY:
                amount += input.amount();
                state = ADDING_MONEY;
                break;
            case SHUT_DOWN:
                state = TERMINAL;
                // why ???
            }
```

Comment: I would ask the author of the book about this. But IMO it's not necessary to use `default` unless you will handle it.

Comment: Please edit, your link to the book is not showing in the question.

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza  IMO you'r right!   but  i wonder it's best answer?!

Comment: @ BadZen  donwload one . page 748

Comment: There's no reason at all to have the default there.  It could potentially cause a slight difference in the produced bytecode if the compiler does not optimize (Oracle JDK does not), so it's technically possible to get different semantics at runtime (if your classloader intercepts the bytecode and explicitly chacks it for default in the switch table.  But no sane person will ever care about that.

Comment: I would consider the use of `default` as a good habit. In your case you don't have to do anything for the `default` case. However, sometimes you do have to initialize a variable, or return a value etc in `switch(...){...}`. Then you have to write something for the `default` case or compilation error occurs.   Also, some people would prefer the use of `default: break;` for readability. They may want to cover "all" the cases to avoid ambiguity, though this is a bit trivial and to some extent unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not *necessary*, it is a style thing. [In the Google Java style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.8.4.3-switch-default) it says:

> 4.8.4.3 The default case is present
>
> Each switch statement includes a default statement group, even if it
>   contains no code.

In the event you have a different case added that isn't handled in the switch, it would be nice to have a default that did something, whether to throw an exception, do logging, or whatever, to inform someone there was a case that isn't handled. Having a default label makes it more apparent that there is a spot where some code like this needs to go.

It may be Bruce Eckel decided to make his code comply with the Google style guide, and added this as a result. Following agreed-on conventions can be a good thing even if you don't agree with all of them, there is an argument that ["form is liberating"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/discipline-makes-strong-developers/).